# Como elimino un item dentro de un objecto que esta dentro de un arreglo?

Tags: javascript

necesito eliminar un item que existe dentro de un objecto dentro de un arreglo de objectos en Javascript.

tengo algo como asi:

```
<pre>
<code>
const arreglo = [{

fecha: '2020',
nombre: 'luis'

},
{

fecha: '2019',
nombre: 'jose'

},
{

fecha: '2018',
nombre: 'alberto'

}
]
</code>
</pre>
```

Mi idea es quitar espeficamente el item llamado "Fecha".

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arreglo = [{

fecha: '2020',
nombre: 'luis'

},
{

fecha: '2019',
nombre: 'jose'

},
{

fecha: '2018',
nombre: 'alberto'

}
];

// recorrer cada elemento del arreglo y eliminar su 
// propiedad fecha
arreglo.forEach(e => delete e.fecha);

console.log(arreglo);
```

Comment: gracias!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

También puedes usar la función map para no destruir el arreglo

```
var nombres = arreglo.map(item => ({nombre: item.nombre}))
```

Eso te regresa solo el nombre de los elementos y conservar el arreglo original, o puedes asignarlo de nuevo a arreglo. Mi recomendación es tratar a los arreglos como objetos inmutables